# Get value in json file with key while ignoring path

Tags: python, json

Let's say I have this type of json file:

```
{
  "body": [
    {
      "content": "abcd"
    },
    {
      "content": "test"
    },
    {
      "paragraph": {
        "content": "ok"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get every value from "content", but I can't go go through every item in body and use the key "content", bcs it hasn't the same path for every item.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt at solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try recursion:

```py
dct = {
    "body": [
        {"content": "abcd"},
        {"content": "test"},
        {"paragraph": {"content": "ok"}},
    ]
}


def get_content(o):
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        for k, v in o.items():
            if k == "content":
                yield v
            else:
                yield from get_content(v)
    elif isinstance(o, list):
        for v in o:
            yield from get_content(v)


print(list(get_content(dct)))
```

Prints:

```
['abcd', 'test', 'ok']
```